# Bulk operation with reactive spring data elasticsearch

Tags: reactive, spring-data-elasticsearch

i want to use the reactive spring data elasticsearch client but I need a bulk operation. Checking the code repository on github and I can't any bulk operation with the reactive client.

Can anyone explain why it's not implemented?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The reactive operations in Spring Data Elasticsearch are a quite new addition, and as stated for example in the Javadoc for the `ReactiveElasticsearchOperations` class:

> Interface that specifies a **basic set** of Elasticsearch operations executed in a reactive way.

The implementation is by no means exhaustive and there surely is quite some stuff missing.

So the best thing to do if you think that there is something missing, is to file an issue in the [Jira](https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAES/issues).